# Why does ios safari oauth 2.0 redirect not work?

Tags: ios, reactjs, next.js, safari

I'm working on a NextJs React app. I am using Oauth 2.0 to let the user connect an external account. On ios safari, the oauth flow does not work for me because the app does not recognize the oauth code in the redirect link of the oauth popup.

I'm opening a new browser window for the user to connect his account like so:

```
const popup = window.open(url, title, `popup,width=${popupWidth},height=${popupHeight},left=${left},top=${top}`);
```

I'm checking for the redirect link that includes the oauth code like this:

```
const searchParams = new URL(popup.location.href).searchParams;
const code = searchParams.get('code');
if (code) {
  popup.close();
  setAuthCode(code);
  timer && clearInterval(timer);
}
```

On all other devices & browsers, this works as expected. The original window waits for the redirect, recognizes the oauth code & closes the window.

On ios safari, the new window opens & the user can connect the account, but nothing happens after the redirect. The user is stuck with two open windows.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? Thanks!